# Consider the unbounded region below $y=e^{2x}$ and $y =e^{-2x}$ , and above $y =0$ over interval $(−\infty, \infty)$. What is the area of this region?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> Consider the unbounded region below $y=e^{2x}$  and $y =e^{-2x}$ , and above $y =0$ over
> interval $(−\infty, \infty)$. What is the area of this region?

How can the area be computed without knowing the terminals ?

Comment: The region has an infinite length in $x$ direction, but the area is finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the obvious symmetry, we have:

$$A=2\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{2x}dx= 2 \lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_a^0 e^{2x}dx=2\lim_{a \to -\infty} \frac12(e^{2x})_a^0 = 1.$$

**Figure:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The area is given by
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{2x}dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-2x}dx = 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-2x}dx$$
because $x \mapsto e^{2x}$ is increasing, $x \mapsto e^{-2x}$ is decreasing, and $e^{2x} = e^{-2x}$ when $x=0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate  next integration step please?

Comment: Didn't the answer by Anton Vrdoljak do exactly that?  If you were asked to do a problem like this, then you are clearly expected to know that the anti-derivative of $e^{ax}$ is $\frac{1}{a}e^{ax}+ C$!